# "function arguments expected near 'levelc'" when using LOVE

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently trying to make a level loading system for a game.

```
function love.filedropped(file)
ofile=io.open(file:getFilename(),"r")
io.input(ofile)
file:close
levelc=io.read()
for i=1,levelc do
levels[i]=io.read()
print levels[i]
end
```

levelc should be the first line of the file, and file:getFilename is the file to open (path included) the project gives an error message on startup, and i've used a similar structure before, but for an output. The error is at line 30, which is the levelc=io.read().
I've tried changing the name of the file pointer (it was "f" before, now "ofile") and i've tried using io.read("*l") instead of io.read() but same result.
EDITS:
-this is a love.filedropped(file)
-i need to open other files from a .txt later and i don't really understand how do do that

Comment: You forgot to mention the error message you get. What is `file`? Why are you not using love2d file system? E.g. https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.lines ? Please avoid images and post the code directly as in https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting

Comment: made the edits, i'm kinda new to stack and coding in general sorry.

Comment: Try `file:close()`

Comment: That's better :) I do not fully understand why it isn't working, but I still recommend not using lua here. The `DroppedFile` object you get has a line iterator. For general usage, check out the example at https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filedropped

Comment: `print(levels[i])`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that's the one! Thanks! (i'm still new to stack, how do i mark your anwser as correct?)

Comment: It was not an answer, just a hint in a comment. Probably Luke will write an answer containing list of all your mistakes about using love2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter given by `love.filedropped` is a [`DroppedFile`](https://love2d.org/wiki/DroppedFile).

In your case helpful could be [`File:lines()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/(File):lines).

For example:

```
function love.filedropped(file)
    -- Open for reading
    file:open("r")
    
    -- Iterate over the lines
    local i = 0
    for line in file:lines() do
        i = i + 1
        levels[i] = line
        print(i, levels[i]) -- Notice the parentheses missing in your code
    end
    
    -- Close the file
    file:close()
end
```

Notice that love2d usually only allows reading/writing files within the save or working directory. Dropped files are an exception.

Unrelated to this answer but things I noticed in your code:

- Use locals, `oFile` should be local
- file:close() required parentheses as its a function call
- Same for the print
- The `filedropped` callback has no `end`

You mentioned reading other files too, to do so, you can either:

- Use [love.filesystem.newFile](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.newFile) and a similar approach as before
- The recommended one-liner [love.filesystem.lines](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.lines)

Comment: i'm making a small-scale project and i've already set it up to use the standard lua i/o, but i'll definately need this! also i messed up the parenthesis oops